# auto resize application in other computer wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i created an application in wpf c# with an 17" lcd monitor... now when i build my application and try to run to other computer like my friend's 10" netbook. the size of my main form is ok but the child window and other main control buttons are still big. it didnt fit the screen... hmmm... note: all of my child windows are created with this xaml header like this:

```
    Background="Transparent" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle="None"        
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: Have you tried having all your controls in a panel control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.. i tried SizeToContent. yes my childwindow are aligned in center but all of my childwindow are still big and even my maincontrol buttons (in my mainwindow, in the leftside. there are buttons)... :)

Comment: i tried to use the viewbox... still i've got a problem in child window.. it still doesnt fit it doesnt resize the width and height

Comment: thank u so much ethicallogics. i finally got it. i dont know if i'm correct. but what i did is i set my resolution property to lowest (not so low) just like 1024 x 768. and adjust everything to my apps... then the sizetocontent... wuhuuuuu! :) thanks